# The order of actions with WHEN CLAUSE

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

1 He said to me his name **when** I gave him the money.

1 I gave 2 he said

That is clear. The next are not clear.

> 2 When I met him he knew the news.
>
> Does it mean that he learnt the news after I met him or that he had
> known it before I met him?
>
> 2a When I met him he didn't know the news. (What does it mean? The news was eliminated after he met me?)
>
> 3 He lived in Germany when I arrived.
>
> Technically, it should mean that he started living in Germany after I
> arrived. But it's strange. Should it be "He have been living in
> Germany when I arrived"? Or is it the case when in real speech this
> logic is neglected?

Comment: He _told me_ his name.

Comment: He told me his name as far as I know is used but not as correct as say a name. After all, it's not a story to be told

Comment: Believe me as a native speaker: _He said his name_ = he spoke it out loud. _He told me his name_ = he informed me what his name was. It is not 'less correct'.

Comment: OK. But "He said his name to me", is it wrong?

Comment: No, but 'He told me his name' is much more idiomatic.

Comment: "He said his name to me" is OK, but you have "He said to me his name", which is wrong.

Comment: Also I don't understand "I gave 2 he said". Are you missing quotation marks or something? Who gave 2 what?

Comment: 1 Can you give some grammar evidence that "He said to me his name" is grammatically wrong. You say it's wrong not just unidiomatic. 2 I don't understand what is not clear. Maybe if you had noticed 1, it would be easier to see the order of the actions.

Answer (score 1):

"When" used as a conjunction does not usually imply sequence; it usually means "at the same time." It *can* be used to mean "immediately afterwards," but it's used in order to focus on the immediacy. So *He said to me his name when I gave him the money* is emphasizing that "*as soon as* I gave him the money, he told me his name."

"Knowing" is a state of being; you *learn* something at one moment, and then you *know* it for a long time. "Know" is rarely used to describe the moment of learning something. So *when I met him, he knew the news* would usually mean "at the time that I met him, he already knew the news." It would usually **not** mean that he learned the news at the same time as, or immediately after, meeting me. If that's the meaning you intend, you could use "learned of" in place of "knew."  If you instead wrote "when *he* met *me*, he knew the news," then I would assume that *meeting you somehow instantly informed him of the news (as would be the case, for example, if the news was that you are visiting from out of town). This is because the focus is on him, so the implication is that it affects him somehow, so I would assume "know" is being used like "learn." (2b) should now be clear: It means "at the time when I met him, he did not yet know the news."

*He lived in Germany when I arrived* means "at the time when I arrived, he was living in Germany." If you used the past perfect ("he *had been living* in Germany"), it would mean "at the time when I arrived, he had been living in Germany [for some time already]." The implications are slightly different, although in most situations either would fit. English speakers often choose the simple past instead of past perfect when the context in unambiguous, just because it's "simpler."

Comment: How about 'when I met her, she knew how to swim', or 'when I met him, he knew how to draw'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey same as knowing the news: *at the time that I met him/her, he already knew how to swim/draw." In those cases, "know" would *never* be used to mean "learn," because the process of learning takes a significant amount of time (whereas learning the news can be instantaneous).

Comment: I don't agree with this "it usually means "at the same time." It seems to me that it means that only when STATIVE VERBS like "know, live" are used.

Comment: I gather that "When I arrived he lived in G." is tantamount to "When I arrived he was living in G", right?

Comment: Yes, it is, and _he was [already] living in G._ is much more natural. Similarly (2) would be expressed as either _When I met him he [already] knew the news_ or _When I met him I told him the news._ (Actually, we would say 'He _had heard_ the news', since 'knew the news' sounds funny.)

Comment: What if he didn't hear but read the news?

Comment: "He had seen the news."